# d3.js linechart different interpolations for different lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

i have created a line Chart and want to change the interpolation of each line.
Here i found a source with different interpolations: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js

Doing it for a lineChart that has only one line: Working fine!
For a chart with **different lines with different interpolations**: don't get it.

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .options({
    margin: {left: 100, bottom: 100},
    x: function(d,i) { return i},
    showXAxis: true,
    showYAxis: true,
    transitionDuration: 250
  })
  ;

    chart.yAxis
       .axisLabel('y axis')
       .tickFormat(d3.format(''))
       .axisLabelDistance(50);

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(dataForChart)
    .call(chart);


  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);


  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});

var dataForChart=function(){

       var section1 = new Array();
       section1.key="Section 1";
       section1.values = new Array();
       section1.color="#1F77B4";
       section1.interpolate='basis';

       var section2 = new Array();
       section2.key="Section2";
       section2.values = new Array();
       section2.color="#2CA02C";
       section2.interpolate='step-before';

        for (i=0;i<12;i++){
            date=new Date(2013,i,1);

            section1.values[i] = {"y" : Math.round(2*i*getRandom(1,2)), "x": i*3};
            section2.values[i] = {"y" : Math.round(6*i+2*getRandom(1,2)), "x": i/1.5};
         }

         function getRandom(min, max) 
         {
            return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
         }

         var dataArray=new Array();
         dataArray.push(section1); //Commenting out section1 or section2 makes it work
         dataArray.push(section2);

       return dataArray;
};
```

by commenting out section1 or section2 at the end of the source makes it work. Then one line appears with the specified interpolation.

Comment: It's not possibly with NVD3; the NVD3 functions just pass whatever value you specify for "interpolate" to the [`d3.svg.line.interpolate()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate) method, which only accepts a string, not a data-based function.  May I ask *why* you want different line-curve styles on the same graph?  That seems to me like a poor design choice.

Comment: i just wanted to do this for demonstration issues. But it is ok if it doesn't work. But what i need is to decide which interpolation is used in the data input array. But this does also not work, like @AmeliaBR says, that it does not accept functions?

Comment: You can always write your own function that accesses the data array to determine what type of interpolation to use.  But you can only use one type of interpolation in each graph, unless you change the NVD3 code.  For demonstration, maybe create a radio-button / list select input that allows the users to chose which option, then sets `chart.interpolate(option); chart.update();` to switch the mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's what you want, but I tried your code and get the two lines with interpolation... but with the same interpolation.

Just call interpolate method on the graph object, like this:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
  .options({
    margin: {left: 100, bottom: 100},
    x: function(d,i) { return i},
    showXAxis: true,
    showYAxis: true,
    transitionDuration: 250
  })
  .interpolate("cardinal");
  ;
```

This applies to both of the sections though...

Comment: thank you for reply, but what I want is to have different lines with different interpolations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the .interpolate atrribute in nv.models.lineChart as following:

```
 lines
    .width(availableWidth)
    .height(availableHeight)
    .interpolate(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.interpolate;}).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled}))
    .color(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.color || color(d, i);
    }).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled }));
```

After that you can use the .interpolate attribute as in your first post!

I also made the change for the line-types in nv.models.multiChart as following:

```
lines1
    .width(availableWidth)
    .height(availableHeight)
    .interpolate(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.interpolate;}).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled && data[i].yAxis == 1 && data[i].type == 'line'}))
    .color(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.color || color[i % color.length];
    }).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled && data[i].yAxis == 1 && data[i].type == 'line'}));

  lines2
    .width(availableWidth)
    .height(availableHeight)
    .interpolate(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.interpolate;}).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled && data[i].yAxis == 2 && data[i].type == 'line'}))
    .color(data.map(function(d,i) {
      return d.color || color[i % color.length];
    }).filter(function(d,i) { return !data[i].disabled && data[i].yAxis == 2 && data[i].type == 'line'}));
```

Found this here : https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/193

Comment: Have you tried this yourself Anil? I apply the patch for nv.models.lineChart but the interpolations are not working...